# Keras: how to re-train a trained model from scratch?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm new to Keras. I'm using [this image-classification code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-image-classification-using-keras/) which works well. Later, I have received an existing model file (.h5) that has already been trained on some images (same classification). I would like to re-use the model (layers, settings, etc) to train on a new set of images from scratch i.e. it should not "remember" anything related to the images it was originally trained on.

I'm not sure of the right terminology to forumlate my question, but I would like to essentially do a `load_model` on the existing .h5 file, without the need to programmatically setup the layers (`model.add(..)` I guess), but still be able to perform `model.fit` as usual, given my new set of images.

What do I need to do to the loaded model to keep its setup but "reset" its knowledge of the previous training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you intend with re-using the settings of the previusly loaded model, but if you want to change only the weights of the model what you can do is something like this:

```
first_model = load_model('my_model')
second_model = load_model('my_model')

second_model.compile(...)

weigths = second_model.get_weigths(second_model)
first_model.set_weigths(weigths)
```

you load the model 2 times and you use one of the models to reset the weigths by recompiling the model, you then set the weigths of your model from the one recompiled, you could also directly use the recompiled model if it is okay, it depends on what you intend with "settings"

Comment: Are you saying that .compile() resets the weights of my model to some initial random value? If so, why can't I simply load one model and compile it before starting to train? Why do I need a second model?

Comment: ye but with compile you also reset hyperparameters like the learning rate on top of resetting the weights, this is why i said that this depends on what you mean by "settings"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Is there a way to compile while preserving all hyperparams as well? Ideally I would like to load the model and run .fit() with the train/validation generators

Comment: then do what i did in the answer

Comment: In your answer, you also ran .compile() which would reset the hyperparameters, right? Unless there is a way to run it without destroying them? I just need to reset the weights..

Comment: yes, this is why i used the recompiled model just to get the weights, i then set the weigths of the first model without recompiling it, you need to use the first model that is not recompiled